# Why doesn't my image get aligned as I like?

Tags: html, css

What's wrong in my CSS? Why doesn't my image go to the center?
I already tried `margin: 0;` and `display: block;` but this doesn't work.

```
<style>
   .card-header img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto; //this one already try
      display: block; //also this one
   }
   .banner-banner {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left: -5px;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #230343 0%, #A558F1 100%);
   }

</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: you made it width:100% so there is no room fo centring

Comment: not sure why all the downvotes.  he came here for help, so help him like @Temani did or move on.  He's new, as were all of us at one time.  let him know that a simple google search for centering an element horizontally will give him what he needs.  don't be upset that you won't be able to increase your rep with his question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are looking to have a card that is divided into header\body\footer (something [like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/))

The image you sent is being given a width of 100% so it doesn't get any place to align itself to the center.

I'd suggest you ether use a background image on the entire card header or change your image to have a width that is lower than it's container.

This will also do the trick if you change the width of the image:

```
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```